# How to prevent Asian characters from breaking lines by words

Tags: javascript, html, css, word-wrap

I'm currently working on an e-commerce website. After translated all products into Japanese, my customer asked to apply the following changes:

By default, product name will be automatically wrapped like this:

```
|  あいうえおかきく　けこさ  |
|  しすせ                  |
```

(I use "|" to show the border of element)
As you see, the second part "けこさしすせ" is divided because of limited width.

What they expected is, just like default English line break method, it should be like:

```
|  あいうえおかきく　       |
|  けこさしすせ            |
```

Considering SEO I cannot simply replace space with br, or change it's structure. Is there anyway I can archive this?

Please see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gsuL6evk/2/) here.

Thanks!

Comment: Since especially Japanese often doesn't use whitespace at all, the rules cannot be the same as for western languages. If you want to enforce this, you may have to wrap each individual whitespace separated chunk into a `span` tag and set the `nowrap` attribute on it. Is this really crucial to have?

Comment: @deceze I see, unfortunately I can only leave the product name pure text for simplifying other guys without html basics and SEO optimisation. Thank you for you reply!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
white-space: nowrap
```

on each part of the text that you hope not to be wrapped around.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

The HTML markup `nobr` can be used but is not recommended.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr

See

> http://jsfiddle.net/zo9oygfk/1/

vs

> http://jsfiddle.net/zo9oygfk/4/

As in your comment, the wrapper having `overflow: hidden` is not affecting it.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Since the wrapper has overflow:hidden, these texts become a single line and being cut off.

Comment: please see updated answer.  the `white-space` is not for the whole line, it is for each portion of the title that is not to be wrapped around

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot change the text inside the wrapper, cuz they are fetched from woocommerce and also I should guarantee the simplicity for those guys without html basis. This is a detailed solution for me , pretty appreciate that!

Comment: I was wondering about the same thing: is there a CSS property that will say: no wrap unless it is white space (such as space or newline).  But I didn't see any that can do that.  If the HTML needs to be marked up as smaller parts, it can be done in PHP or whatever that generated the HTML on the server.  It can be done using JavaScript as well but probably not good, say, for users who do not turn on JavaScript

Comment: Great, I'll explain this to them. Thanks again for your detailed answer!